# how to know which quarter does the current month belongs to ? (in python )

Tags: python-2.7

I want to know to which quarter(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) does the current month belongs to in python. I'm fetching the current date by importing time module as follows:

```
import time
print "Current date "  + time.strftime("%x")
```

any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies but I used some piece of code like this.Please neglect my formatting of code in comments area. I'm still learning.`import datetime import math cur_date = datetime.datetime.now()quarter = ceil(cur_date.month/3)`

Comment: `cur_data.month` is an integer. So, `cur_date.month/3` remains an integer on Python 2.7. `math.ceil` doesn't do anything useful with integers. You code puts Jan (1) into Q0 and Oct (10) into Q3. So its obviously buggy.

Comment: Interesting! I'll sort it out. thanks for finding the bug for me in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying your code, I get this:

```
import time

month = int(time.strftime("%m")) - 1 # minus one, so month starts at 0 (0 to 11)
quarter = month / 3 + 1              # add one, so quarter starts at 1 (1 to 4)
quarter_str = "Q" + str(quarter)     # convert to the "Qx" format string
print quarter_str
```

Or you could use the bisect module:

```
import time
import bisect

quarters = range(1, 12, 3)           # This defines quarters: Q1 as 1, 2, 3, and so on 
month = int(time.strftime("%m"))

quarter = bisect.bisect(quarters, month)
quarter_str = = "Q" + str(quarter)
print quarter_str
```

Comment: Thanks! I used other lines of code which served my purpose. Check it in comments area under my question.

Comment: Well, I have one question for you my friend. The current month is September which should fall in second Quarter (Q2). But after I ran your code it says that its third quarter. Why is that ?

Comment: Jan, Feb, Mar are Q1. Apr, May, Jun are Q2. Jul, Aug, *Sep* are Q3. Oct, Nov, Dec are Q4.

Comment: Actually Apr,May,Jun belongs to Q1. I'm taking financial year.

Comment: You can always wrap the months around if you want to start at a different month. `month = (month + offset) % num_months_in_year` before you computer the quarter. So to start in Apr, `month = (month + 3) % 12`.

Comment: "quarter = month / 3 + 1  " fails for December (month =12)

Answer (score -1):

[`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) does not know about quarters, but you can calculate them from the month:

1. Use [`time.localtime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) to retrieve the current time in the current timezone. This function returns a named tuple with year, month, day of month, hour, minute, second, weekday, day of year, and time zone offset. You will only need the month (`tm_mon`).
2. Use the month to calculate the quarter. If the first quarter starts with January and ends with March, the second quarter starts with April and ends with June, etc. then this is as easy as dividing by 4 without remainder and adding 1 (for 1..3 // 4 == 0, 0 + 1 == 1, 4..6 // 4 == 1, 1 + 1 == 2, etc.). If your definition of what a quarter is differs (e.g. companies may choose different start dates for their financial quarters), you have to adjust the calculation accordingly.

Comment: Oh! I thought there will be some other method to avoid the calculation like some module to be imported or something like that!:P

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer There might be a third party module, but to me it looks like a bit of overkill to add a module to replace this one-liner.